# How to extract certain values after ''/'' from a cell using Python - Openpyxl?

Tags: python, automation, openpyxl

Below is the data -

I want to extract from column A , only the date which is present after '/'  and paste it in column H ( to the empty column present as below) preferably using Openpyxl (python)

[image]

Output -

[image]

This is my code below:

```
  wb= load_workbook(r'')
  ws=wb.active
  for row in range(len(ws['A'])):

      match =re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] 
               |1[0- 2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",ws.cell(row,1).value)
      if match:
      ws.cell(row,8).value = match[1]
```

And the error i get here is -

> raise ValueError("Row or column values must be at least 1")
> ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1

Is it possible to extract only 10 characters after'/' ? Please help me with this.

Comment: Please include code from your own attempts and ask questions about that.

Comment: am new to this, so need help from scratch, hope the query is understandable

Comment: No, sorry this is not a code writing service. Read the openpyxl documentation and update your question with some code.

Comment: Also, why do you need to use python? Pls refer to this [article](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/06/01/split-text-string-excel/), you can do it using a simple excel formula

Comment: I know how to do it in excel, There is a requirement for me to automate this in python,

Comment: @CharlieClark, I have updated the code .. please help me solve this

Comment: Why have you written `for row in range(len(ws['A']))`? Just loop over the cells directly.

Comment: Now am getting this error - 

 if row < 1 or column < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Cell' and 'int'

Comment: Update your code and include the whole exception, though if the code is unchanged then you've ignored my advice and are still doing it wrong.

Comment: If you're still stumped some things to note; 1) A python range by default starts at 0, Excel rows start at 1 (that is your error message). 2) Doubt you will get a match on your regex. Does it need to do such in-depth check? do you expect to have an incorrect date like 32.14.2020 in Excel? I presume it really only needs to check for 2 digits, dot, 2 digits, dot, 4 digits. Start simple, add more complexity if needed after everything else works. 3) tuples also start at 0 not 1 so match[1] is the second match not the first.